# Average using numpy.mean till a number N

Tags: python, numpy, average, mean

Suppose I have a list a with 10 elements

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

and I want to take the average of only `N` elements, say `4`, that is,
`average of [1,2,3,4]` How do I do this using `Numpy`?

Normally I can iterate over a list, but that would cost me an additional list which I don't want to `invest`.

[Numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.5.x/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) documentation did not provide me something.

Comment: You mean `np.mean(a[:4])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have a numpy array and not a list, just slice the first `N` elements and use the `mean` method.

(If you want to have things work regardless of whether it's a list or a numpy array, use `np.mean(a[:4])`, as @larsmans suggested above.)

For example

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)
print x
print 'Mean of first 4 items in x', x[:4].mean()
```

Slicing the a numpy array i.e. `y = x[:4]` doesn't make a copy with a numpy array (as it would with a list). Instead, it returns a "view" into `x`.  This doesn't copy memory, so it's very efficient.

Slicing and operating on portions of numpy arrays is a very common idiom. Have a look at the documentation for more information: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html‎

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the extra list overhead, you could write a simple mean function:

```
def mean_of_n(arr, n):
    index = 0
    current_sum = 0
    n = min(n, len(arr))
    while index < n:
        current_sum += arr[index]
        index += 1
    return float(current_sum) / n
```